# How can I insert row to a sheet using cell value of another sheet using apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet called database (see picture 1) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by5Yv.png), and each item from the database sheet also have a separate sheets (see picture 2 for example sheet of items in database sheet)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uupfA.png). How can I copy columns  H, L, M, N, O, P of database sheet to the last row of each item sheets?

Comment: Have you looked at =IMPORTRANGE? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en

Comment: yes, but what I want to do is, to copy the values of columns H,L,M,N,O and P to each item sheets listed in database sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) function is quite useful in this scenario, the rest is just copying and pasting ranges using [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()).

```
function myFunction() {
  // databse values
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dataBase = ss.getSheetByName("database").getRange("E2:P17").getValues();
  
  // Iterates through items
  for (let i = 0; i < dataBase.length; i++) {
    // Item name
    let itemName = dataBase[i][0];

    // Data columns H-P
    let data = dataBase[i].slice(3);
    // Removes columns I-K
    data.splice(1,3);

    // Pastes values
    ss.getSheetByName(itemName).appendRow(data);
  }
}
```